# Refresh whole user entered data in WinForms application when I click a button

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I refresh whole user entered data in WinForms application? When I click a button
I want to clear all my controls i.e. User entered data in windows form application on a button click.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const string message = "Are you sure you want to clear data";
            const string caption = "Please Conform";
            var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);
                RowNumberSettings();
                //Refresh();
            }
        }
```

here is my code It clears only Datagridview ...

Comment: You can try to Dispose the current instance of the Form,and create a new instance quickly.This way you can reset all the controls' quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do it, but I like to do it like this:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
{
     Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

     func = (controls) =>
     {
         foreach (Control control in controls)
             if (control is TextBox)
                 (control as TextBox).Clear();
             else
                 func(control.Controls);
     };

     func(Controls);
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You may want to accept this as answer if this satisfies your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon what data you are having.

Make refresh function and bind all the data in the controls within that function.

On the button click event, just call the refresh function.

```
 void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh()
    }
```

Comment: In Tabcontrol i have a datagridview , tabcontrol and other txtbox controls ..i want to clear all user entered data

Comment: just make that gridview's datasource=null

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use MVVM pattern for your forms. Here is some [guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290532/Binding-Helpers-Separation-of-UI-view-model-and-da).

MVVM provides you a clear separation of view (your forms) and data (what is displayed). You can easily update any part without significant changes in other parts. And you can manipulate any values in the back-end code without knowledge how they are displayed.

In case of usage MVVM you will be able just to recreate the underlying view-model object and all GUI controls will be empty or have their default values (depends on how you implement the view-model).

Comment: While I totally agree that MVVM is a nice pattern, it seems totally overkill for the OP's simple issue.

Comment: @Dan-o it's much more efficient way in case when forms has different types of controls. And needless to say that you have a total control over your displayed data. I can't imagine an approach of checking each type of control and resetting it's value manually in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `Controls` collection (recursively) and handle each control.

Example (in VB):

```
Sub ResetControls(container as Container)
  For Each control As Control In container.Controls
    '  TODO:  Check the control type and reset its value
    '
    '  TODO:  If the control is a container, call ResetControls(control)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple, but not efficient approach in terms of supporting code and updating logic in the future, because after adding any new type of control this function should be updated.